# MySql .net connector Membership Provider defaulting MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql, membership

I just downloaded and installed the most recent MySQL .net connector, 6.3.6 and it connects to the DB just fine. My problem is with the web.config settings I have set for it. It seems that the MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters property is hard coded to '1'.

I've changed this to 0, 5, or any other number. I even setup a web page to just display the properties of the provider. If I change the values in the web.config, the values update. It seems that MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters won't change.

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" autogenerateschema="true" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" 
         type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" 
         applicationName="MySite" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters="0" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="44"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Again, the DB connection works just fine, reason I did not post the connection string. The min password length at 44 was just for testing.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipProvider p = Membership.Provider;

    Literal1.Text = "Min Pass length: " + p.MinRequiredPasswordLength.ToString() + 
        "<br/> Required non-alpha: " + p.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters.ToString() +
        "<br/>App Name: " + p.ApplicationName;
}
```

Of the three I only tested, only MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters stays at '1' no matter what I change it to in the web.config. I even changed it to 'abcd' and received no .NET runtime errors. Me thinks it is hard coded some where or I'm not using the right property name in the web.config. I copied the web.config value straight from and example in the documentation that came with the MySQL .net connector.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer to my post at www.asp.net. The property for minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters in my web.config file was wrong. Needed to be minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters (small 'a').